# How to subtract the 'for' loop counter in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, range

The structure that I know for the `for` loop in Python is as follows:

```
for i in range(10)
```

and then range is actually `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]`. Now there is a problem here and that is I want to reduce the counter of my loop by putting a line `i-=1`, however that does not show the result I expect.

The following example is a structure same as `while(True)` in e.g. Java and C, but here it works and the counter in the loop ignores the line which was intended to reduce it.

```
for i in range(10):
    i-=1
    print i
```

And it generates the output:

```
-1
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

What should I do to get what I want with the `for` loop! I know it can be easily done by a while as follows:

```
i=0
while(i<10):
   i-=1
   print i
   i+=1
```

Here is the Java code as an example and I expect to see an endless loop printing `-1`:

Here is the Java code:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

    public class HelloWorld{

         public static void main(String []args){
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                i--;
                out.println(i);
            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Use a while loop and your own counter when you want to tinker with the loop variable.

Comment: I find the question open to interpretation. Please show us the Java or C loop you are unsuccessfully trying to implement in Python.

Comment: What is your actual, current code? What's the expected output? Do you want to do a backwards loop, or are you actually trying to modify the loop (e.g. repeat elements at certain conditions)?

Comment: @HenryKeiter, I just explained up there my intension. To get a while(True)

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @Naji: To get `while True:`, write `while True:`. What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I really don't know why I am getting minus votes. I followed the simple input output structure for the question, wrote an example!

Comment: Well, I have no idea why you'd want that, but you can't accomplish that with a python for loop (at least not easily). You'll just want a to use a `while True:` loop.

Comment: @Hoopdady, I was just trying to follow SSCCE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Otherwise I am using it in a different context

Comment: K. I'm just saying the code doesn't make a lot of sense from a standalone perspective. If you just want an endless loop that prints `-1` forever. You don't need the iterator. You could just `while 1: print(-1)`. If we new the exact problem you were trying to solve, we might be of more help. Either way, in python, you can't manipulate the iterator in python in a `for` loop like you can in C, so you'll have to use a `while` loop.

Comment: Now this was the answer I was expecting. To know that its not possible to change the iterator. I was generating a sample and I was trying to control for some boundary conditions, which though I wanted the same sample size but I had to reject the boundary cases.

Answer (score 5):

The `range` function takes 3 arguments: start, stop, and step:

```
for i in range(-1, 9):
  yield i
```

To go in reverse

```
for i in range(10, 0, -1):
  yield i
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range).

**Edit:**

Of course, there's nothing to stop you from using the `range` directly. Thus `map(print, range(10, 0, -1))` will print them all to the screen, while `range(10, 0, -1)` will give you access to the integers directly.

Comment: This gives the following error:
`yield i
SyntaxError: 'yield' outside function`

Comment: @Naji That's correct. If `yield` is not nested within a function it throws that error. You could also just use `range(10, 0, -1)` plain.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why what you tried to do will not work on python is because range returns a slice of integers.

```
>> range(10) 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

and the for statement iterates over each element of the slice. Here is what you tried to execute:

```
for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
    i = i - 1
    print i
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the iterator variable like this. The for in python here is more similar to a foreach.

To achieve the behavior I assume you want you should do it like this:

```
i = 0
while (i<10):
    i-=1
    print i
    i+=1
```

although it looks a bit silly compared to:

```
while(True):
    print(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [e for e in xrange(10, 0, -1)]
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This is horribly redundant. Just do `range(10, 0, -1)` to accomplish that.